# Spidweb crack on wall the looks to have gapping where to start to find the cause?

Tags: walls, foundation, crack, water-damage

[image]Wall above kitchen door way center of the house looks to be sticking out dry to touch house is brick ranch on a slab and built in the early 60’s [image]

Is there a way to verify no water/foundation issues? Once we cut into drywall to patch is there a clear way to tell if it is a structural problem?

Comment: If you'll take the [tour], you'll note that this is a _Question_ & Answer forum. Care to [edit] this to actually ask a question?

Comment: What's on the other side of that wall?

Comment: The kitchen and the wall looks completely normal

Comment: TBH, it looks like just a simple, standard failure of a drywall tape joint. Not enough mud was applied, so it's cracking off. We have large swathes of that at our church right now. :(